# PHP Apache windows upload limit with Drupal

Tags: windows, apache-2.2, php, drupal, upload

I am running php 5 with apache on windows 2003. I have changed the the upload_max_filesize to 50mb. I have saved the file and restarted apache. When I try a file upload in Drupalit says the maximum file size is set at 8mb allowed by php (this is reported where you set the limit for drupal). Do you know where I would change this option to make it more. I believe it to be a server setting rather than an application one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the post_max_size in php.ini:

post_max_size = 8M   (max size that a script can POST back)

Comment: Just a note, for whatever reason, upload_max_filesize is only 50% of post_max_size.  So if you wanted a 10mb upload you need the following configs:     * upload_max_filesize = 10M
    * post_max_size = 20M